# Problem in converting sprintf to C#

Tags: c#, string, formatting, printf

i have this line I need to write in C#

```
sprintf(
  currentTAG,
  "%2.2X%2.2X,%2.2X%2.2X",
  hBuffer[ presentPtr+1 ],
  hBuffer[ presentPtr ],
  hBuffer[ presentPtr+3 ],
  hBuffer[ presentPtr+2 ] );
```

`hbuffer` is a `uchar` array.

In C# I have the same data in a byte array and I need to implement this line...

Please help...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if this works:

```
byte[] hBuffer = { ... };
int presentPtr = 0;
string currentTAG = string.Format("{0:X2}{1:X2},{2:X2}{3:X2}",
                          hBuffer[p+1],
                          hBuffer[p],
                          hBuffer[p + 3],
                          hBuffer[p + 2]);
```

This is another option but less efficient:

```
byte[] hBuffer = { ... };
int presentPtr = 0;
string currentTAG = string.Format("{0}{1},{2}{3}",
                          hBuffer[p+1].ToString("X2"),
                          hBuffer[p].ToString("X2"),
                          hBuffer[p + 3].ToString("X2"),
                          hBuffer[p + 2].ToString("X2"));
```

> Converting each byte of hBuffer to a
>   string, as in the second example, is
>   less efficient. The first example will
>   give you better performance,
>   especially if you do this many times,
>   by virtue of not spamming the garbage
>   collector.

*[From the top of my head]* In C/C++ `%2.2X` outputs the value in hexadecimal using upper case letters and at least two letters (left padded with zero).

In C++ the next example outputs `01 61` in the console:

```
unsigned char test[] = { 0x01, 'a' };
printf("%2.2X %2.2X", test[0], test[1]);
```

Using the information above, the following C# snippet outputs also `01 61` in the console:

```
byte[] test = { 0x01, (byte) 'a' };
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:X2} {1:X2}", test[0], test[1]));
```

Comment: Converting each byte of hBuffer to a string, as in the second example, is less efficient. The first example will give you better performance, especially if you do this many times, by virtue of not spamming the garbage collector.

Comment: You are correct @David Yam. That was why I pointed the other option first. But I add a disclaimer with your comment to make the point clear.

Answer (score 2):

[Composite Formatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd.aspx): This page discusses how to use the `string.Format()` function.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [String.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1csw23d.aspx) method.